# Getting wrong number of pages in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, paging

I am doing paging in spring boot. I am having 32 records on a list.  I am trying to get these lists in pages with a page size of 5. When I check for pages from 0 to 3, I am getting correct total elements(5 on each page). But when I check for the last page, it is giving me one less element in the list(1 element on the last page, but it should return 2) and also, the total count of elements is reduced by one.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Students s JOIN FETCH s.Teachers WHERE s.Teachers IN (:Teachers)", countQuery = "SELECT count(DISTINCT s) FROM Students s" +
             " WHERE s.Teachers IN (:Teachers)")
    Page<Students> findByStd(@Param("Teachers") List<Teacher> Teacher, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Either you made a typo in your query or it is simply not correct. In your query you refer to `b` whereas in your count you are refering to `s` . Also why supply both queries why not simply use `findByTeachersIn(List<Teacher> teacher, Pageable pageable)`. Spring Data will nog create both queries for you. Also make sure you are really setting the correct page size (looks like you still have the default of 10 in your `Pageable` you are passing in ).

Comment: @M.Deinum Updated query. Also, we have to mention countQuery if we use pagination with Join fetch.

Comment: Check JOIN FETCH query and COUNT query records are the same count.

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye We can't use JOIN fetch in count query. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Abhishek I mean pls check the first query give how many records. And the second count query give how many records. I doubt the two queries are not the same count

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye I checked manually running the second query and it's giving the correct response

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT s 
FROM Students s JOIN FETCH s.Teachers 
WHERE s.Teachers IN (:Teachers)
```

```sql
SELECT count(DISTINCT s) 
FROM Students s
WHERE s.Teachers IN (:Teachers)
```

Let's see

```
FROM Students s JOIN Teachers
```

is different with

```
FROM Students s WHERE s.Teachers IN (:Teachers)
```

thereforce, pageNumber is wrong.

Comment: keep 2 queries are similarity. Maybe `countQuery = SELECT count(DISTINCT s) 
FROM Students s WHERE s.Teachers IN (:Teachers)"` you should test by yourself because I haven't database.